# Does the probability density function remain normalized after marginalization?

Tags: bayesian, normalization, likelihood

Let's say, we have data $D$ and two parameters $A$ and $B$ in a model. I want to marginalize the likelihood $p(D \mid A, B)$ over $B$ as

$$
p(D \mid A) = \int p(D \mid A, B) p(B) {\rm d}B.
$$
I know that $B_0$ maximizes $p(D \mid A, B)$ for a given combination of $D$ and $A$, i.e. $B_0 = f(D, A)$. I want to approximate $p(D \mid A, B)$ as
$$
p(D \mid A, B) \approx p(D \mid A, B_0) \exp\left[-(B-B_0)^2/2\sigma^2\right].
$$

For a uniform prior $U[-W/2, W/2]$ on $B$ with $W \gg \sigma$, I have $p(B) = 1/W$ for $B<W$ and $p(B)=0$ otherwise. From the first equation, the marginalized likelihood $p(D \mid A)$ is
$$
p(D \mid A) \approx p(D \mid A, B_0) \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}{W}. 
$$

Now, $p(D \mid A)$ is normalized as

$$
\int p(D \mid A) {\rm d}D = 1.
$$

I think, $p(D \mid A, B_0)$ should also be normalized, but it's not as from the above equation I get

$$
\int p(D \mid A, B_0) \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}{W} {\rm d}D = 1 \\
\Rightarrow \int p(D \mid A, B_0) {\rm d}D = \frac{W}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}.
$$

Why is $p(D \mid A, B_0)$ not normalized? I feel like the reason could be the dependency of $B_0$ on $\{D,A\}$, but it is not clear to me. Or, is there something wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 3):

First [following notations above, although upper cases are usually reserved for either events or random variables]
$$p(D \mid A) = \int p(D \mid A, B) p(B) {\rm d}B$$
only if $A$ and $B$ are independent, else it should be
$$p(D \mid A) = \int p(D \mid A, B) p(B|A) {\rm d}B$$
Second, the rhs in
$$p(D \mid A, B) \approx p(D \mid A, B_0) \exp\left[-(B-B_0)^2/2\sigma^2\right]$$uses an unnormalised Normal density, hence it is hardly surprising that the marginal of the rhs is not normalised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $p(D \mid A, B)$ is by definition normalized as $\int p(D \mid A, B) {\rm d} D = 1$, so should be $p(D \mid A, B_0) \exp\left [ -(B - B_0)^2/2\sigma^2 \right]$ within the approximation. Albeit, the density here is $p_{D\mid A, B}$. After marginalizing over $B$, the density becomes $p_{D\mid A}$ which is normalized. My question was why $p_{D \mid A, B_0}$ is not normalized. After further pondering, I think it's indeed due to the dependency of $B_0$ on ${D, A}$. So, in this context $p_{D \mid A, B_0}$ doesn't make sense as a valid probability distribution. Am I wrong?